# Stopping an SQL Cursor with one of two conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a cursor that I want to stop running based on one of two conditions.
One is based on the data of a table, and the other is based on the fetch status.
Right now the cursor ignores both and just keeps running.

This a part of what I currently have:

```sql
OPEN DemandCur
FETCH NEXT FROM DemandCur INTO
    @....,
    @++++


While @index  > 0 or  @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 

BEGIN

select
 ....,
 ++++
from......

--After doing some stuff here---

FETCH NEXT FROM DemandCur INTO 
    @....,
    @++++

End
Close DemandCur
Deallocate DemandCur
```

Comment: Try change `or` to `and`?

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be a AND, and not a OR? Currently if any of the conditions are true, the query will keep running. and in this case @@FETCH_STATUS will be true, until the end

Comment: Spock, @index might be at 0 before cursor goes through all the records.  That is why I have a or and not and.

Comment: As long as @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 is part of your condition and you're using a OR, the while will continue to loop until the cursor is finished, no matter what the value of index is. Try setting index to 1 before the loop, and change the OR to an AND

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are nasty because the `FETCH NEXT` statement typically ends up duplicated. To avoid this, I prefer an infinite `WHILE` loop that you then break out of. This also allows you to break on any condition you like:

```
OPEN DemandCur
WHILE 1 = 1 BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM DemandCur INTO
        @....,
        @++++
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK;

    IF @index <= 0 BREAK;   -- or after "stuff", depending on what you're doing

    select
     ....,
     ++++
    from......

    --Some stuff here---
END;
CLOSE DemandCur
DEALLOCATE DemandCur
```

Comment: Jeroen, I'm getting "Cannot use a BREAK statement outside the scope of a WHILE statement" when I placed the @index if statement after the @@fetchstatus or after doing my stuff.

Comment: @user2220670: Then you have inadvertently closed the scope of the `WHILE`. The code as posted definitely works -- are you sure your `BEGIN ... END`s are in order?

Comment: Joreon, This is what I have: OPEN DemandCur
While 1 = 1
FETCH NEXT FROM DemandCur INTO
 @...., @++++ 
IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 BREAK;
IF @index <= 0 BREAK;


BEGIN

Comment: @user2220670: comments aren't suitable for code blocks. You can edit your answer to include the new code you now have (don't replace the original!)

Comment: @user2220670: sorry for the confusion. I meant to write "you can edit your *question*", of course. Note that your comment is missing `BEGIN` after `WHILE 1 = 1`, which would indeed not work.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen.  I moved the begin and it did stop but only after it went through all the records even after @index had dropped to zero or below.